# Glide and recyclerview, too much memory

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory, android-glide

I use Glide to download images(~4Kb each) and a recyclerview with a gridlayout to display it. I store images url in an lru cache. In the onBindViewHolder() I get the image url and display it with Glide as a follow:

```
 Glide.with(mMainActivity).load(item.getPosterPath()).thumbnail(0.5f).into(holder.posterPath);
```

The problem is that after 300 images the app goes in out of memory exception, this is the Android profiler info:
[image]

This is my recyclerview adapter:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_content, parent, false));
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = mItems.get(position);
    if (item!= null) {
        holder.itemView.setTag(item);
        Glide.with(mMainActivity).load(item.getPosterPath()).apply(ro).thumbnail(0.5f).into(holder.posterPath);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    }
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView posterPath;
    private TextView originalName;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        posterPath = itemView.findViewById(R.id.poster);
    }
}
```

This is my structure:

```
public static LruCache<Integer, Item> mItemMap = new LruCache<>(20);
```

Where an item is:

```
public class Item {
    private String mId;
    private String mOriginalName;
    private String mFirstAirDate;
    private String mLanguage;
    private String mOverview;
    private String mPosterPath;
    private int itemPos;

    Item(String id, String originalName, String firstAirDate, String language, String posterPath, String overview, int itemPos) {
        this.mId = id;
        this.mOriginalName = originalName;
        this.mFirstAirDate = firstAirDate;
        this.mLanguage = language;
        this.mOverview = overview;
        this.mPosterPath = posterPath;
        this.itemPos = itemPos;
    }

    /**
     * Getters.
     */
}
```

My recyclerview scroll adapter:

```
    @Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
    totalItemCount = mGridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
    firstVisibleItem = mGridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (loading) {
        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
        }
    }
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        current_page++;
        onLoadMore(current_page);

        loading = true;
    }
}
```

And this is how I get new data from internet:

```
   public void newItem() {
    currentPage++;
    String URL = "myurl";
    RestClient.get(URL, null, mHandler);
}
```

Where mHandler is:

```
mHandler = new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

            try {
                results = (JSONArray) response.get("results");
                for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                    obj = results.getJSONObject(i);

                    id = obj.get("id").toString();
                    posterPath = obj.get("poster_path").toString();

                    if (!posterPath.equals("null")) {
                        mItem.add(ItemList.createItem(id, null, null, null, POSTER_BASE_URL+posterPath, null, itemPos));
                        itemPos++;
                    }
                }
                notifySubscriber();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("JSON", "Error in parsing json.");
            }
        }
    };
```

And this is my RestClient:

```
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);

}
```

[image]

Where and when all the byte[] allocations are made?

Comment: Show the usage of the cache.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman How can I do?

Comment: You will need to show more “something”, I mean, a single screenshot and a generic line won’t do much unfortunately. In general, unless you need to, try to avoid using an Activity/Fragment as Context unless you’re sure what the context is used for (and who will retain the reference). I’d ask you to try your best to expand your question with more information, because as it sits, it’s a guess for everyone, including you. :)

Comment: Ok thanks! I've updated with some code.

Answer (score 4):

I really don’t see what may be happening, but two things I’d keep an eye on:

1. I’d look at http://bumptech.github.io/glide/int/recyclerview.html to see if you’re following their correct practices.
2. I’d use `Glide.with(holder.getContext()).load(…`.

You are passing or using `mMainActivity` there which is, what I assume a reference to your `Activity`. There is absolutely no need to have an entire Activity referenced there. You have Views and you’re loading images in the context of the views (the ViewHolder that you’re binding to), so remove that leak from there.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've updated with  Glide.with(holder.itemView) but nothing is changed.

Comment: However, I'm sure the problem isn't the images because the android profiler shows poor usage of ram for the images. The problem is that I don't understand where and when all the byte[] allocations are made(you can see that in the latest screen)

Comment: Can you share a link to one of the images?

Comment: Hahahahahah I meant a couple of the images you load in your recycler view ;)

Comment: Ah ok, sorry :) here is: http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/ooBGRQBdbGzBxAVfExiO8r7kloA.jpg

Comment: They are very small, is that a real image or a thumbnail? Anyway… I’m not sure what’s happening. I wonder if your LruCache is not working as expected. What version are you using (check the import)? Glide, support lib, or the framework version?

Comment: I solved the memory leaks adding holder.posterPath.setImageDrawable(null); in the onViewRecycled event.

Comment: Glad to hear, though I’m not sure if that isn’t hiding another problem. Who is retaining the views, that in turn, retain the image (byte[])? A total mystery. :)